# How to change the "username" displayed for the django username field to something different like "code name" or "nickname"

Tags: python, django

I was trying to customize my user but at the same time keep it as simple as possible, I wanted the username field to display as "nickname" but still keep all the behaviour and properties of the username.
What I do when I am extending a django class is the ctrl+click thing on vscode to go inspect the super class (I was extending the AbstractUser this time) and here is the code for the username field in django's AbstractUser:

```
username = models.CharField(
        _('username'),
        max_length=150,
        unique=True,
        help_text=_('Required. 150 characters or fewer. Letters, digits and @/./+/-/_ only.'),
        validators=[username_validator],
        error_messages={
            'unique': _("A user with that username already exists."),
        },
    )
```

Usually, I'd just paste the field in my custom class and override the `_('username')` with `_('nickname')` but that doesn't feel like the right thing to do here as there's a lot going on in that field, plus I'd have to also import the username_validator to keep that behaviour.

Now my question is; how do I override the verbose_name field (I guess that is what it's called) and still keep other behaviours.

Comment: do you mean in a form?

Comment: yes, and in the Django admin too @ekrem-Üçüncü

Answer (score 1):

Basing on [this article](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/application_development/9781787281141/5/ch05lvl1sec35/customizing-field-labels), as you said it yourself, you have to explicitly specify `verbose_name` while creating the model:

```
class Person(models.Model): 
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30) 
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, verbose_name='Lasty')
```

Tried it, seems okay (at least on edit form, but I guess effect is the same for list view):
[image]

Considering `User` model is kinda special, I guess you could simply subclass `AbstractUser` class like this:

```
class MyUser(AbstractUser):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=40, unique=True, verbose_name="Nickname")
```

Considering we're subclassing **full-blown user**, as per [this paragraph](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-a-manager-for-a-custom-user-model), I believe we won't have to do anything else (register custom managers etc.).